# Prove that $3^n$ is not $O(2^n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I have this question in my assignment. I need to prove, using only the definition of $O(\cdot)$, that $3^n$ is not $O(2^n)$. It is obviously true for any $n \geq 1$.

To prove  $3^n \in O(2^n)$, we must find $n_0$, $c$ such that $f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
3^n &\leq c \cdot 2^n\\
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n& \leq c
\end{aligned}
$$

I am stuck here....
I could use a log here, but I don't see the use

Any hint?

**UPDATE**

$$
\begin{aligned}
3^n &\geq c \cdot 2^n\\
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n& \geq c\\
n \log(3/2) &\geq \frac{\log c}{\log 3/2}\\
n &\geq \log \frac{2c}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

For every $n \geq \log \frac{2c}{3}$, $3^n \geq 2^n$. Therefore, $3^n$ is not $O(2^n)$.

Comment: $(\frac{3}{2})^n$ is unbounded

Comment: So you mean that for any value of $c$ I can take, $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$ will be bigger... Which means that I cannot find a value of $c$ that will respect my statement... clever, thanks!

Comment: For any *specific* value of $n$, $O(2^n) = O(1) = O(3^n)$. The point of big-oh notation is that it says something informative when $n$ is a variable ranging over some interval $(n_0, \infty)$, not when $n$ has any particular value.

Comment: You didn't take that logarithm quite right.

Comment: @dfeuer, how's that?

Comment: Where did the $\frac{}{\log 3/2}$ come from?

Comment: $\log c/\log(3/2) \not = \log (2c/3)$

Comment: Neither of those is right. Go step by step.

Comment: @JustinD. How $\frac{logc}{log(3/2)} = log(\frac {2c}{3})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is to prove that no value of $c$ can work.

One way of doing so is to show that the equation $(3/2)^n \geq c$ has infinitely many solutions for $n$. Do you see why that is?

Comment: You mean finitely many?

Comment: Hmm.. I would say there is no solution to $(3/2)^n \geq c$, because as said in a comment, $(3/2)^n$ is unbounded, so whatever value of $c$ I can take,$(3/2)^n$ is going to be bigger than $c$... Oh well, no solution to $<$

Comment: @Pedro: Whoops, I had my inequality pointing the wrong way.

Comment: @Justin: IF you take $c=2$, then $(3/2)^1$ is not bigger than $2$! But there are lots of $n$ for which $(3/2)^n$ is bigger than 2, right?

Comment: @Hurkyl Sure, that was the other option. =)

Comment: I updated my answer... not sure if I did the right thing...

Comment: @Justin: Looks good!

Comment: @Hurkyl, thank you for the tremendous help!

Answer (score 3):

**Contradiction:**   Assume: $${3^n} \in O\;({2^n})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaG4mamaaCa
% aaleqabaGaamOBaaaakiabgIGiolaad+eacaaMe8Uaaiikaiaaikda
% daahaaWcbeqaaiaad6gaaaGccaGGPaaaaa!3EEE!
$$
therefore:
$${3^n} \le c{2^n} \to \frac{{{3^n}}}{{{2^n}}} \le c \to {(\frac{3}{2})^n} \le c \to \log {(\frac{3}{2})^n} \le \log c \to n \le \frac{{\log c}}{{\log 1.5}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaaeaaaaaaaaa8
% qacaaIZaWdamaaCaaaleqabaWdbiaad6gaaaGcpaGaeyizImQaam4y
% a8qacaaIYaWdamaaCaaaleqabaWdbiaad6gaaaGcpaGaeyOKH46aaS
% aaaeaapeGaaG4ma8aadaahaaWcbeqaa8qacaWGUbaaaaGcpaqaa8qa
% caaIYaWdamaaCaaaleqabaWdbiaad6gaaaaaaOWdaiabgsMiJkaado
% gacqGHsgIRcaGGOaWaaSaaaeaapeGaaG4maaWdaeaapeGaaGOmaaaa
% paGaaiykamaaCaaaleqabaGaamOBaaaakiabgsMiJkaadogacqGHsg
% IRciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaGGOaWaaSaaaeaapeGaaG4maaWdaeaa
% peGaaGOmaaaapaGaaiykamaaCaaaleqabaGaamOBaaaakiabgsMiJk
% GacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaadogacqGHsgIRcaWGUbGaeyizIm6aaSaa
% aeaaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGJbaabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNb
% GaaGymaiaac6cacaaI1aaaaaaa!6A5D!
$$

Since 'c' is a positive constant,
$$\log c = Const. \to \frac{{\log c}}{{\log 1.5}} = Const. \to n \le Const.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbGaam4yaiabg2da9iaadoeacaWGVbGaamOBaiaadohacaWG
% 0bGaaiOlaiabgkziUoaalaaabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaam4yaa
% qaaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaaigdacaGGUaGaaGynaaaacqGH9aqp
% caWGdbGaam4Baiaad6gacaWGZbGaamiDaiaac6cacqGHsgIRcaWGUb
% GaeyizImQaam4qaiaad+gacaWGUbGaam4CaiaadshacaGGUaaaaa!5AE3!
$$
But we have to find:
$${n_0}\;{\rm{such}}\;{\rm{that}},{\rm{for}}\;any\;n \ge {n_0}\;(n \to \infty )\;{\rm{satisfies}}\;{\rm{our}}\;{\rm{inequality}}\;{\rm{(}}n \le Const.{\rm{)}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOBamaaBa
% aaleaacaaIWaaabeaakiaaysW7caqGZbGaaeyDaiaabogacaqGObGa
% aGjbVlaabshacaqGObGaaeyyaiaabshacaGGSaGaaeOzaiaab+gaca
% qGYbGaaGjbVlaadggacaWGUbGaamyEaiaaysW7caWGUbGaeyyzImRa
% amOBamaaBaaaleaacaaIWaaabeaakiaaysW7caGGOaGaamOBaiabgk
% ziUkabg6HiLkaacMcacaaMe8Uaae4CaiaabggacaqG0bGaaeyAaiaa
% bohacaqGMbGaaeyAaiaabwgacaqGZbGaaGjbVlaab+gacaqG1bGaae
% OCaiaaysW7caqGPbGaaeOBaiaabwgacaqGXbGaaeyDaiaabggacaqG
% SbGaaeyAaiaabshacaqG5bGaaGjbVlaabIcacaWGUbGaeyizImQaam
% 4qaiaad+gacaWGUbGaam4CaiaadshacaGGUaGaaeykaaaa!7BCD!
$$
$${\rm{Since}}\;{\rm{for}}\;{\rm{any}}\;{n_0},\;n \to \infty \;\;{\rm{conflicts}}\;{\rm{with}}\;\;n \le Const.,\;{\rm{we}}\;{\rm{can}}\;{\rm{say:}}\;{{\rm{3}}^n} \notin O\;({2^n})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaae4uaiaabM
% gacaqGUbGaae4yaiaabwgacaaMe8UaaeOzaiaab+gacaqGYbGaaGjb
% VlaabggacaqGUbGaaeyEaiaaysW7caWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicdaae
% qaaOGaaiilaiaaysW7caWGUbGaeyOKH4QaeyOhIuQaaGjbVlaaysW7
% caqGJbGaae4Baiaab6gacaqGMbGaaeiBaiaabMgacaqGJbGaaeiDai
% aabohacaaMe8Uaae4DaiaabMgacaqG0bGaaeiAaiaaysW7caaMe8Ua
% amOBaiabgsMiJkaadoeacaWGVbGaamOBaiaadohacaWG0bGaaiOlai
% aacYcacaaMe8Uaae4DaiaabwgacaaMe8Uaae4yaiaabggacaqGUbGa
% aGjbVlaabohacaqGHbGaaeyEaiaabQdacaaMe8Uaae4mamaaCaaale
% qabaGaamOBaaaakiabgMGiplaad+eacaaMe8Uaaiikaiaaikdadaah
% aaWcbeqaaiaad6gaaaGccaGGPaaaaa!811A!
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to prove this is *not* the case. Let's first rearrange your definition of $O(2^n)$ a little:

$f$ is $O(2^n)$ if there exist $n_0$ and $C$ such that, for any $n\geq n_0$, $f(n) \leq C\, 2^n$.

Now, work out carefully what it means to say $3^n$ is *not* $O(2^n)$:

$f$ is not $O(2^n)$ if, for every $n_0$ and $C$, there exists $n \geq n_0$ such that $f(n) > C \, 2^n$.

So, if I hand you *any* $C$ and $n_0$, you have to find $n \geq n_0$ so that $3^n > C \,2^n$. If it isn't clear how to prove it yet, try finding an appropriate $n$ if I give you $C = 700$ and $n_0 = 4$, then do the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of taking a logarithm is a good one. $\log (3/2)^n = n\log (3/2)$. That should pretty much finish off your argument, as long as you know logarithms are increasing.

Comment: I updated my answer with that!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I'm not sure what you don't understand. Logarithms are increasing, so when $a,b>0$, $a\le b\implies \log a\le\log b$. This is a simple proof by contradiction.

Comment: @dfeuer Nevermind. I just thought the phrase was oddly put.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By Bernoulli inequality

$$(\frac{3}{2})^n \geq 1+\frac{n}{2}$$